# Is it legally possible to embed my own youtube videos to my own subscrbtion based app?

Tags: reactjs, youtube, youtube-api, video-streaming, youtube-data-api

I want to create a subscrbtion based video streaming App (people have to subscribe to see my videos in the app).

I'm trying to embed my own YouTube videos to the app without YouTube logo and with "Only people with the link can see" restriction. Is it legally possible to embed my videos to subscrbtion based app ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can make a app like that you can but you cant hide it is streaming from youtube, nothing is illegal till the content you are monetizing is yours.

Comment: You mean its illegal to hide the YouTube logo ?

i found this artice how to do techicaly : https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

Comment: Also im not going to monetize my video on YouTube (AdSense ). I'll will only earn subscrbtion income ( when people subscribe to my app )